# jQuery validation custom error message display for radio button

Tags: forms, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation and trying to get the error message for a pair of radio buttons to show up before the first button.

Here is the validation:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (element.attr("type") == "radio")
   error.insertBefore(element.first());
 else
   error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="full">
<label id="sample">Have you received your sample pack?</label>

<input type="radio" name="sample" id="sample_yes" value="yes" />
<label for="eliteflexsample_yes">Yes</label>

<input type="radio" name="sample" id="sample_no" value="no" />
<label for="eliteflexsample_no">No</label>    
</div>
```

Right now the error is showing up after the first radio button.

Comment: Try to log the value of type out to the console.
Add this line before the if:
    console.log(element.attr("type"));

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').validate({

        // your validation options,

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
                error.insertBefore(element);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }

    });

});​
```

[**Working Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Aw/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Aw/2/

Comment: This works great!  I also was able to append it to the end of the parent of my radio group by doing:

    element.parent().append( error );

Comment: To append the error to the end of all items in the radio button group use last-child like this: element.last-child().append(error);