# JQuery validation formatting

Tags: jquery, error-handling

When I validate my radio buttons my default error message is displayed in between radio button and radio button text as in the following picture.

[image]

**I want to display the default error message right after the radio button text in red color. How to do this?**

JQuery Code:

```
$(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#myForm").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            radio1: "required",
            radio2: "required",
            radio3: "required",
            radio4: "required",
            name: "required",
            datepicker: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                //email: true
            },
            email_confirm: {
                required: true,
                //email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 10
            }
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your contact name",
            phone: "Please enter your phone",
            email: "Please enter your email",
            email_confirm: "Please re-enter your email to confirm"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert ("Successful");
            //form.submit();
        }
    });

  });
```

Comment: You should change in your html tag, and use css for it.

Comment: Check out errorPlacement property for validate function

Comment: @NeerajKumar What did you mean by change html and css? An error is produced by JQuery automatically.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123055/jquery-validation-custom-error-message-display-for-radio-button